# 3 primers to know if Homozygous, Heterozygous or WT

Tags: genetics, homework, pcr

In this imaginary experiment, I am using T-DNA to make an insertional mutagenesis that will get randomly inserted into the DNA where it might get inserted within a gene, disrupting it.

In order to get homozygous individuals, If I working on plants, I could self-pollinate this particular plant that has had this gene disrupted making homozygous offspring.

In order to prove that, I can do a PCR using 3 primers.

My question is, why 3 primers? I would use 4 primers!
I have been researching it and trying to understand it for myself for a while, but I do not reach any positive conclusion. I think it should be pretty basic and I am missing something.

I think I need forward and reverse primers for the T-DNA, but what about the 3rd primer? If I only use these two primers, though, I will not be able to distinguish between the homozygous and heterozygous.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this imaginary experiment come frome an article or a book? Could you add a reference? Is the goal to disrupt a particular gene or to search for mutants with paticular phenotype? Do you know the sequence of the gene which has been disrupted in the parent plant before self-polination? If the gene is known one or two primers can be designed to bind the gene and not the T-DNA.

Comment: As an exercise: can you imagine any scenario under which 2 of those 4 primers could be combined into a single primer, for 3 total? (Genotyping T-DNAs is generally done with only 3, I can confirm). Also, any reference would be helpful. Is this a homework or study problem?

Comment: Maybe two different PCR tests where PCR gives positive results, one where the insert was successful, and one where no insertion happened.

Comment: This is from one of my lectures, where the professor introduced T-DNA mutations and said that I would need 3 primers with no explanation. I do not have any reference though. What I can add is the following: if I do an electrophoresis next, the WT would have a of 900 bp, the Heterozygous would have two bands, 900 and 400 bp, and the Homozygous would habve 1 band of 400 bp.

Comment: From statistical viewpoint, one needs at least three measurements to have a meaningful estimate of mean and variance . Even if you do no such estimations, these considerations are likely the reason for recommending 3 primers. If you can have more in a reasonable amount fo time and at reasonable cost, it is only better!

Comment: As I think that this is in danger of turning into an extended Socratic comments-fest without really getting anywhere, I'll just post [this link][1] which discusses T-DNA insertion confirmation. I'll note that this site is easily accessible by Google, which is a good place to look first, to help us help you! 
  [1]: https://bitesizebio.com/35392/genotyping-t-dna-insertion-mutants/

Comment: Thanks Maximilian! I found this website too when I changed my Google search strategy. Now I am trying to understand it properly.

Comment: @Laura can you point directly to e.g. a quote or a figure or other part of this site that is confusing you? Have you followed the links?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out again. This part confuses me: " Flanking primers [...] The chosen primer pairs span this insertion site. Furthermore, the primer pair needs to cover a region long enough that the PCR reaction will not be able to amplify the insertion mutant". The flanking primers are not  in the left and right border of the T-DNA but outside of it, in random positions of the DNA? The third one is it the T-DNA, as I understand. These random primers will be designed in a way that will give you 900bp band except if they fall where the T-DNA is?

Comment: If it is like that, it means that you will have to amplify every region of the genome in order to find the T-DNA, right?